# How to implement database searching in datagrid?

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, datagrid

I am working on a project for my customer. I wrote code to search items from SQL using vb.net.

Now my code working fine. When I search data using itemid it show me data in all related textboxes but not in datagrid. Here is my code:

```vb
Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Server= DESKTOP-QN6F623; Database = dbo_main; Integrated Security = true")
Dim command As New SqlCommand("select * from items where itemnumber=@itemnumber", connection)
command.Parameters.Add("@itemnumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ItemnumberTextBox.Text
Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
Dim table As New DataTable()
adapter.Fill(table)
ItemnameTextBox.Text = ""
If table.Rows.Count() > 0 Then
    ' return only 1 row
    ItemnameTextBox.Text = table.Rows(0)(1).ToString()
    ItembarcodeTextBox.Text = table.Rows(0)(2).ToString()
    ItemnameTextBox.Text = table.Rows(0)(3).ToString()
    ItemdescriptionTextBox.Text = table.Rows(0)(4).ToString()
    ItemcolorTextBox.Text = table.Rows(0)(5).ToString()
    ItemsizeTextBox.Text = table.Rows(0)(6).ToString()
    ItemmaterialComboBox.Text = table.Rows(0)(7).ToString()
    ItemavailablestockTextBox.Text = table.Rows(0)(8).ToString()
    ItempricesTextBox.Text = table.Rows(0)(9).ToString()
    ItemsuppliersTextBox.Text = table.Rows(0)(10).ToString()
    ItembrandnameComboBox.Text = table.Rows(0)(12).ToString()
    ItemlocationComboBox.Text = table.Rows(0)(13).ToString()
Else
    MessageBox.Show("NO Data Found")
End If
```

I only want to show searched data in textboxes as well as in datagrid with highlighting.

Comment: Where is your datagrid code?

Comment: Your post is quite unclear. There's no code there related to a grid so why would you expect it to show anything in a grid?  Are you saying, without actually saying, that you have already populated the grid with all the data and you then want to find a specific record in that and select it, as well as displaying data from that record In your `TextBoxes`?  If so then you should not be querying the database at all because you already have the data  You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Comment: Check this for search using textbox https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/satyapriyanayak/search-records-using-textbox-in-VB-Net2/

Comment: Thank you for your reply kumar.and sorry for bad englisth

my question is

i have a items form where user add items and below that i have same items datagrid.

now i want user to enter item number in "item id" and when user press enter...he must get details of that ID number in all textboxes as well as in datagrid .

Comment: i wrote codes for textboxes only means when user write item number in item ID then he can get all data in related textboxes but not in datagrid